# postgresql query plan strange behaviour

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I must select the rows in one table (table_A fairly small < 10K rows) that have no corresponding rows in another table (table_B over 500K rows) based on column_X (table_B has an index, btree, on that column).
If I use the following query:

```
select a.column1,
    a.column2,
    a.column3,
    a.column_X,
    b.column_X
from table_A a
left outer join table_B b on a.column_X = b.column_X
where a.column_X <> 0
    and b.column_X is null
```

the query (168 resulting rows) is executed in about 600ms.
If, on the other hand, I try a different query:

```
select column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    column_X
from table_A
where column_X not in (
        select column_X
        from table_B
        where column_X is not null
        )
    and column_X <> 0
```

it takes around 8 minutes to retrieve the same 168 rows. column_X is of type bigint and casting seems to make no difference (in the second query the index is never used).
Any idea?

Comment: please share `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result - see the web https://explain.depesz.com/ for sharing.

Comment: Note: the `where column_X is not null` in the subquery is not needed.

Comment: @wildplasser if `column_X` is nullable, then it *is* really needed. Without it, if the column actually contains a `NULL` value, the `NOT IN` expression (and any `IN` expression) would result in `NULL` (this is required by the ANSI SQL standard). And that is precisely why PostgreSQL won't turn that query into an anti-join.

Comment: ... f.ex. `column_X NOT IN (1, NULL)` is equivalent to `column_X <> 1 AND column_X <> NULL`, which is equivalent to `column_X <> 1 AND NULL`, which will always be `NULL`.

Comment: IMHO `column_x NOT IN(1, NULL)` is equivalent to `NOT ( column_x = 1 OR column_x = NULL)`, which would become `NOT (columns_x = 1 OR NULL)` ergo: even if the nulls were returned by the subquery, they could never compare equal to any value (null or non-null)

Answer (score 1):

The `NOT IN` subselect is much worse optimized than any other. Due different semantic PostgreSQL cannot to use antijoin. If you can, don't use this pattern. Use `NOT EXISTS` instead, or outer join.